# How do I populate a list box in ASP .NET from a data source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, datasource

I know for a fact that the function below (Database.GetTables) is bringing back the value/s that I want. However, when I try to do the binding to the list box, nothing populates in it. Am I missing anything? What's the correct way to populate a list box from a datasource?

```
protected void ddlDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (ddlDatabases.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                lbxTables.DataSource = Database.GetTables(ddlServers.Text, ddlDatabases.Text);
                ddlDatabases.DataValueField = "name";
                ddlDatabases.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

I have also tried:

```
ddlDatabases.DataTextField = "name";
```

And no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting by setting up the DataSource on your listbox control, but end up calling DataBind on the dropdown menu.

Try this:

```
protected void ddlDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlDatabases.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        lbxTables.DataSource = Database.GetTables(ddlServers.Text, ddlDatabases.value);
        lbxTables.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You can also add in the `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` on `lbxTables` there before `lbxTables.DataBind();`

Comment: Do I need to have both DataValueField and DataTextField or can I have just one or the other?

Comment: I think that if you don't set the DataTextField, it will default to whatever .ToString() returns on each object you're binding the ListBox to.  I would set it.  As for the value, I'm pretty sure if you don't set it, it will always be null.  I would set them, I just don't know what the classes your GetTables method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to bind lbxTables or ddlDatabases?  Above you're not binding any data to the listbox only setting the datasource.  Instead, do this:

```
            lbxTables.DataSource = Database.GetTables(ddlServers.Text, ddlDatabases.Text);  
            lbxTables.DataTextField = "name";
            lbxTables.DataValueField = "name";  
            lbxTables.DataBind();
```

Comment: wow, stupid mistake of mine. the names were incorrect (i was copying and pasting some code and didnt even see I hadn't changed this one.) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values to show up for a listBox you'll have to add

```
lbxTables.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind the drop down list and the list box but you need for each one of them to:

1. Set a data source (Database.GetTables(ddlServers.Text, ddlDatabases.Text); ).
2. Call Control.Databind() for each control that need binding to a data source (this means one for the drop down list and one for the listbox)
3. Optional, set the data value and data text fields.

Have a good day,